# I cannot install any package using npm (need for react-router-dom)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

When I try to install something in the beginning I see I some gibberish text and It is taking too long and in the end it is giving me an error. On top of that Yarn is not helping.

```
 npm version 6.14.10,  node v14.15.1 ,  yarn v * 1.22.10
```

I see this gibberish text when I tried to install with yarn.

```
yarn add v1.22.10
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "C:\\Users\\DavrService™\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-hoist-non-react-statics-3.3.2-ece0acaf71d62c2969c2ec59feff42a4b1a85b45-integrity\\node_modules\\hoist-non-react-statics\\.yarn-metadata.json: Unexpected token \u0000 in JSON at position 0".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "D:\\real\\test\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

When I tried with npm it says `npm warn deprecated` and this kind of stuff.

Comment: did you run `npm init` first before installing packages?

Comment: I think the first thing to try is always deleting the node_modules folder and running `npm i` or `npm i -g` if you are installing packages globally. But I think your question needs more details. Does it happen differently for any other packages? Are you trying to install it globally or localy? `Unexpected token \u0000 in JSON at position 0` means the first item in the JSON is `null`. I do not recommend mixing `yarn` and `npm`. Choose one and stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run these commands (In order):

```
npm cache clear -force

npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npm i -g create-react-app

npm i -g npm

npx create-react-app myapp
```

Comment: The last line creates a new project or updates ?

Comment: Yeah, you can change the last command according to your needs!